# Problems while doing a line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, curves, multiple-integral, line-integrals, greens-theorem

let $C$ be a closed $C^1$path (oriented counterclock wise) consisting of a piece of $y^2=2(x+2)$ and the vertical segment $x=2$, and $F$ is a vector field such that $$F(x,y)=\left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right)=(P,Q)$$
evaluate the integral along $C$ using green's theorm.

let $P$ be the region bounded by $C$, then the double integral will look like this $$I=\oint_CF=\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{2x+4}}^{\sqrt{2x+4}}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\,dy\,dx$$
I have two problems the first one is that the bounds are quite hard so I have to change variables but I don't know which map is the best,  and the second one is that the integrand is equal to $0$ which means that $I$ is $0$ as well, but my textbook says that it's $8$.

Comment: You cannot apply Green's Theorem. Your textbook has hypotheses for the theorem. What are they?

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ are $C^1$ functions on a region $A$ which is the interior of a piecewise $C^1$ path parametrized counterclockwise. you wanna say that $P,Q$ aren't $C^1$ ?@TedShifrin

Comment: Where are $P$ and $Q$ not even defined?

Comment: at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ @TedShifrin

Comment: Now draw your curve $C$ carefully.

Comment: the region $P$ consists of the point $(0,0)$, but how I'm supposed to evaluate this integral without green's theorem?@TedShifrin

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is not $8$. Your textbook should show you an example like this. Draw a circle centered at the origin that lies inside your curve. Now use Green’s Theorem on the region between the two curves.

Comment: What substitution should I use to simplify this region?

Comment: Huh? What is the integrand of your double integral? You already know this. But the boundary of the region now has two pieces. One you can do easily.

Comment: but the integrand is still $0$, so I got $0$ as an answer?

Comment: No. Reread what I’ve said.